# Connect two php rest api's

Tags: php, api, rest, connection

What is the best way to connect 2 php rest api's.

The rest API's are 2 external systems whit good documentation.

I know how to use API but my question is what is the best way to connect them together.

Do i need a API Connetor platform or?

searching for many hours ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "connecto two APIs"? APIs are passive, how could you "connect" such thing?

Comment: Why do the APIs need to be connected? What are the APIs? What are you actually trying to do? https://xyproblem.info/